# JS Slice only removes Items when they were in the Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to remove the first Item so that all other move up in an Array I create with

```
..
Queue: [],
..
```

and dynamically push Items into.
I later use slice to remove them and have then next Item be the first one.

```
..
thread.Queue.slice(0, 1);
..
```

It should return the first Item of the Array, which it does, but it should also remove it from the array and move all other up.

Here is a example which shows, that is neither working in the Browser. (I found this 'behaviour' in Node.js)

http://jsfiddle.net/bTrsE/

or rather

http://gyazo.com/b3dcdbf4f74642c04fe1c1025f225a08.png

Comment: [Here is the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the "slice" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.Slice = Is an implementation of SubArray, From an array you want to extract certain elements from the index and return a new array.

*Example:*

var cars = ['Nissan','Honda','Toyota'];

var bestCars = cars.splice(0,1);

console.log(bestCars);

//This should output **Nissan** Because i like Nissan

For your problem you should be looking **Array.Splice()**, ***splice adds / removes an element from the index***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: I didn't even notice that there is Array.slice and Array.splice, should read more carefully

Answer (score 1):

The `.slice()` method does not alter the original array. It returns a shallow copy of the portion of the array you asked for.

Comment: Well why does it then alter the Array in the first example?

Comment: @BeryJu what "first example" are you talking about?  It just does not do that.

Comment: @BeryJu in your jsfiddle both the examples do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't know why that is, it just worked. But here you can see the behaviour http://gyazo.com/b3dcdbf4f74642c04fe1c1025f225a08.png

Comment: @BeryJu well that doesn't happen when I try it in Node.js either. If you're seeing that behavior, you're seeing either a broken implementation, or else something has overridden the native "slice" method in your environment.